# With XSLT Can i extract the 2 first digits from a number

Tags: xslt, xpath

I'm trying to extract the 2 first digits from a number.

I have this XML:

```
<extraccio data="01-05-2013" tipus_objecte="5">
    <objRegistral>
           <categoria id="69">2A. CATEGORIA</categoria>
            <cadastral/>
            <web>www.campingelcarlitos.com</web>
            <email>info@campingelcarlitos.com</email>
            <adreca>
                <no_normalitzada>Cra. N-II, km 658,7</no_normalitzada>
                <tipus_via id="28">Ctra</tipus_via>
                <nom_via>N-II</nom_via>
                <num>km 658,7</num>
                <bloc/>
                <escala/>
                <pis/>
                <porta/>
                **<cp>08350</cp>**
                <municipi id="893">Arenys de Mar</municipi>
                <inframunicipi/>
                <comarca id="21">Maresme</comarca>
                <provincia id="8">BARCELONA</provincia>
                <comunitat/>
                <marca_turistica>COSTA DE BARCELONA-MARESME</marca_turistica>
                <utm_x>464187</utm_x>
                <utm_y>4603963</utm_y>
                <utm_z/>
            </adreca>
            .......
```

I need to extract the 2 first digits from the tag `<cp>..</cp>`

I have this code XSLT:

The error is that i cant compare string to integer

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
        version="2.0">
        <xsl:template match="/">
            <campings>
                <xsl:for-each select="extraccio/objRegistral/dades_generals/adreca[substring(cp,2)= 08]">
                    <camping>
                        <nom><xsl:value-of select="municipi"/></nom>
                    </camping>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </campings>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In

```
<xsl:for-each select="extraccio/objRegistral/dades_generals/adreca[substring(cp,2)= 08]">
```

you need to express the value you are looking for as a string

```
...[starts-with(cp,'08')]
```